# Check if a file exists using a text file

Tags: python, csv, operating-system

I have a folder (Molecules) with many sdf files (M00001.sdf, M00002.sdf and so on) representing different molecules. I also have a csv where each row represents the a molecule (M00001, M00002 etc). 
I'm writing a code in order to get files on Molecules folder if their name is a row on the csv file.

First attempt

```
import os
path_to_files = '/path_to_folder/Molecules' # path to Molecules folder

for files in os.listdir(path_to_files):
    names = os.path.splitext(files)[0] # get the basename (molecule name)
        with open('molecules.csv') as ligs: # Open the csv file of molecules names
            for hits in ligs:
                if names == hits:
                    print names, hits
                else:
                    print 'File is not here'
```

However this returns nothing on the command line (literally nothing). What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this is the best way (I only know that the following code works for my data) but if your *molecule.csv* has the standard csv format, i.e. "molecule1,molecule2,molecule3 ...", you can try to rearrange your code in this way:

```
import os
import csv
path_to_files = '/path_to_folder/Molecules' # path to Molecules folder

for files in os.listdir(path_to_files):
    names = os.path.basename(files)
    names = names.replace(".sdf","")
    with open('molecules.csv','r') as ligs:
        content = csv.reader(ligs)
        for elem in content:
            for hits in elem:
                if names == hits:
                    print names, hits
                else:
                    print 'File is not here'
```

See [csv File Reading and Writing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) for csv module

Comment: It is actually printing the else statement.

Comment: @MarcosSantana Be sure that names and hits are really equal ( because if you have "molecule1.sdf" as _name_ and "molecule1" as _hits_, you'll have the else statement). Check with **print names** and **print hits** in the right places.

Comment: Just checked it. when i print names it shows molecule1, just as when i print hits. I really don't know why it's not working. To be sure I checked by just searching molecule1.sdf on the folder and it is there.

Comment: Using your code each elem in content is a list (each molecule is a list of one element, the molecule name) instead of a string. Maybe this is why it's not working?

Comment: In my data, this works because _hits_ is an element of the list _elem_, that is a list of strings. So there is a comparison ( i.e. == ) between _names_ (that is a string) and every _hits_ (so a string which is an element of a list of strings). Do you have the same types of variables in the comparison?

Comment: Yeah. Both are strings. I checked it with:                                                   
 for files in os.listdir(path_to_files):
 names = os.path.splitext(files)[0]
 print type(names)

Comment: I edited the answer, try now with 'os.path.basename' and 'names.replace()'. My comparison was between folders, so there wasn't the same situation as yours. Please tell me what the edited code does.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with a rather brute approach

```
import os
import csv
import shutil

path_to_files = None # path to Molecules folder
new_path = None # new folder to save files
os.mkdir(new_path) # create the folder to store the molecules

hits = open('molecules.csv', 'r') 

ligands = []

for line in hits:
    lig = line.rstrip('\n')
    ligands.append(lig)

for files in os.listdir(path_to_files):
    molecule_name = os.path.splitext(files)[0]
    full_name = '/' + molecule_name + '.sdf'
    old_file = path_to_files + full_name
    new_file = new_path + full_name
    if molecule_name in ligands:
        shutil.copy(old_file, new_file)
```